# Polymer1: How to force template filter update when other property changed

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Please refer to the code below, is there a way to force the template to update after `pageNumber` changes? Currently the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#filtering-and-sorting-lists) only lets you to update the template if the sub property of the list changes using `observe` attribute. Here I have got a legitimate case where I need to update the template based off the property outside the list.

```
<dom-module id="dummy-list">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{getPageListItems(pageNumber)}}" 
              filter="paginateList">
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'dummy-list',
        properties: {
            pageNumber: Number,
            pageSize: Number
        },
        paginateList: function(item) {
            var index = this.tableData.indexOf(item);
            var indexOneStart = index + 1;
            var itemRightBound = this.pageNumber * this.pageSize;
            return index +1 >= itemRightBound - this.pageSize && indexOneStart <= itemRightBound;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need `X` to update when `Y` changes, and `X` and `Y` are unrelated, you have to add another variable to your function `getPageListItems` that will trigger when change is detected to either.

For example, you can have a boolean variable called `YChanged` that you simply flip whenever the variable `Y` changes. And your `getPageListItems`-function becomes `getPageListItems(X, YChanged)`.

That way the function will be called when either `X` or `YChanged` is modified.